# Multi-Language Support for Android Softkeyboard

Tags: android, multilingual, android-softkeyboard

Currently, I am developing a softkeyboard for Android using SoftKeyboard source code which is available in the SDK.

But I want to add in multi-language support for the keyboard (similar to what is available in the native keyboard). But this portion is not available in the SoftKeyboard source code.

Any idea how could I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Android (f/w 1.5+) on screen keyboard for multiple languages](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/downloads/list)

Comment: Hi, but for this, the languages are installed as separate packages. i want to integrate the languages together with the softkeyboard such that user could choose from the settings, similar to the native keyboard now. Any idea how could implement it?